# Toolbar Items not working due to smaller screen size

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I have five `ToolbarItem`s set to appear in the `topBarTrailing` position. When the app is run on smaller devices or when the text size of the device is increased, 2/3 toolbar items combine into a menu item. However, tapping it doesn't display the expected popup, and I'm encountering this issue in the debugger.

> Called -[UIContextMenuInteraction updateVisibleMenuWithBlock:] while no context menu is visible. This won't do anything.

```
struct ToolBarBugTest: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {}, label: {
            Text("Tap Me")
        })
        .padding()
        .navigationTitle("My Navigation")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                Button {
                    print("Tapped")
                } label : {
                    Image(systemName: "eye")
                }
            }
            
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                // same as above
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                // same as above
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                // same as above
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                // same as above
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have used NavigationView as well but it will keep adding the items on toolbar without making the menu.

Comment: Use `ToolbarItemGroup`?  Where is your `NavigationStack` or `NavigationView`, by the way?

Comment: NavigationStack is in entry point of app

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Label("Eye", systemImage: "eye")` instead of `Image(systemName: "eye")` inside the Button label:

```
Button {
    print("Tapped")
} label : {
    Label("Eye label", systemImage: "eye")
}
```

All `ToolbarItem`s that are hidden by the system will be grouped together inside a menu. For displaying that menu, SwiftUI needs the label, which is rendered in addition to the image.